# How to copy paste code without unnecessary target action link on XCode?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, copy-paste, target-action

When I create a new project and copy paste code from the old project,
the target action link between the pasted method and storyboard in the 
old project will be added.

But I don't want the old action target link. If I click on the target action 
dot on the left side of method, it'll bring me to the storyboard in the 
old project.

So far, my way to fix it is modify method's name, like "foo" to "foo2".
Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Add Files to <your project>` to wipe out all unnecessary dependencies.

Comment: I didn't checkout which project this file in. This might work, thanks a lot. And sorry for that I deleted the project and did not verify this method.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just delete the connection and reconnect it to the new action target, or maybe putting it into something like notepad++ first (havnt tried that, just a thought)

Comment: Delete the connection will delete the one in old storyboard.
If I change file name, it will work. And I tried copy paste by notepad++, too, it didn't work.
This problem will be a big tackle if I want to copy a project and want to modify it, when I need to copy paste a lot from the old storyboard.
At last, I left this question unsolved. But still thanks for answering.